# How to convert jQRangeSlider date values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jQRangeSlider plugin to create a date range slider. However, every time I try to get the max or min values, I get a detailed random date instead. For example, when I try to do:

```
var dateSliderMax = $("#slider").dateRangeSlider("max");
console.log(dateSliderMax.toString());
```

The following string is returned:

> Fri Feb 11 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

I want to get the exact maximum value and also I want the format to be in: YYYY/MM/DD. How do I accomplish this? Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5j1qy9sj/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the date like so:

```
myDate = Date(dateSliderMax.toString());

console.log((myDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + myDate.getDate() + "/" + myDate.getFullYear());
```

Comment: It says getMonth() is not a function